# Mojo SDI Cables

Tags: untagged

Anyone know of anywhere I can buy a Mojo SDI DVI - 7 BNC cable from in the UK? Can only find a couple of places via google and they both want to charge a fortune for postage! Theres no way it costs 10 pounds to post a cable!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this'll help, but you might want to try the following sites:

[Creative Video](http://www.creativevideo.co.uk/index.php?t=category//Cables//)

[Blue Cow Cables](http://www.bluecowcables.com/)